# package amt: unnest tracks produces a list-like object of class NULL

Tags: r, tidyr

I am not sure whether this is an `amt` or a `tidyr` issue, but there is no `amt` tag yet, so here we are.

When working with nested tracks, any calculation (e.g. `step_lengths`) done in the nested tracks creates a new "list-like" column outside the "data" column, with the same number of rows. I am not sure that is the desired outcome, I'd rather have it added to the nested dataset inside the "data" column, but that's fine, it can be easily solved by unnesting and nesting again (in theory). However, unnest produces this weird list-like object of class NULL, and although I have managed to find a workaround to turn it back into a dataframe, then I need to use make_tracks and nest again to go back to the starting point, which is annoying. Code below with a reprex

**First make the dataset**

```
library(random)
test_df <- data.frame(id = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100), 
                  lon = runif(min = -9, max = -6, n = 300),
                  lat = runif(min = 51, max = 55, n = 300), 
                  covar1 = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 300), 
                  covar2 = c(randomStrings(n=300, len=3, unique = F, 
                                         upperalpha = T, loweralpha = F, 
                                         digits = F)))
```

**Now make it a nested track**

```
test_tracks <- test_df %>% 
  make_track(lon, lat, 
             all_cols = T,
             crs = 4326, 
             check_duplicates = FALSE, 
             verbose = TRUE) %>% 
  nest(data = c(-id))
```

**Calculate step lengths**

```
test_tracks2 <- test_tracks %>% 
  mutate(sl = map(data, step_lengths))
```

This produces a nested df that has an additional "list" column, sl

```
> str(test_tracks2, 2)
nested_track [3 × 3] (S3: nested_track/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id  : chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
 $ data:List of 3
 $ sl  :List of 3
```

**Unnest**

```
test_tracks3 <- test_tracks2 %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(data, sl))
```

This produces a list, but of class NULL

```
> class(test_tracks3)
[1] "NULL"
> str(test_tracks3)
List of 6
 $ id    : chr [1:300] "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ x_    : num [1:300] -7.67 -7.96 -8.39 -7.26 -8.49 ...
 $ y_    : num [1:300] 54.3 53.6 54.8 51.9 52.2 ...
 $ covar1: num [1:300] 55.028 0.772 76.037 64.362 34.512 ...
 $ covar2: chr [1:300] "KRU" "RJL" "RVG" "BUW" ...
 $ sl    : num [1:300] 0.718 1.28 3.087 1.261 0.648 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "NULL"
 - attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:300] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

I can turn this list back to a normal df with do.call, but other dplyr or tibble methods won't work

```
x <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, test_tracks3))
> str(x)
'data.frame':   300 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ id    : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ x_    : chr  "-7.67035690904595" "-7.96027435711585" "-8.38539077946916" "-7.25699410191737" ...
 $ y_    : chr  "54.2703927513212" "53.6132442755625" "54.8205336350948" "51.9466292150319" ...
 $ covar1: chr  "55.0277820788324" "0.772069441154599" "76.0366528760642" "64.3617564812303" ...
 $ covar2: chr  "KRU" "RJL" "RVG" "BUW" ...
 $ sl    : chr  "0.718259177377767" "1.27994983112401" "3.08749181012144" "1.26120128657495" ...
```

However it is a plain df now, and all the variables have lost their format (they are all chr) which is not ideal.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why this is happening, but another workaround is to nest 'id' prior to  making the track itself.

```
test_df <- data.frame(id = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100), 
                      lon = runif(min = -9, max = -6, n = 300),
                      lat = runif(min = 51, max = 55, n = 300), 
                      covar1 = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 300), 
                      covar2 = c(randomStrings(n=300, len=3, unique = F, 
                                               upperalpha = T, loweralpha = F, 
                                               digits = F)))

test_tracks <- test_df %>% 
  nest(data = -id) %>%
  mutate(trk = map(data, function(d) {
    make_track(d, lon, lat, 
    all_cols = T,
    crs = 4326, 
    check_duplicates = FALSE, 
    verbose = TRUE)}))

test_tracks2 = test_tracks %>% 
  mutate(sl = map(trk, amt::step_lengths))

test_tracks3 <- test_tracks2 %>%
  select(-c(data)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(cols=c(trk, sl))
```

Answer (score 0):

I always approach this kind of calculations like this:

```
library(random)
library(amt)
test_df <- data.frame(id = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100), 
                      lon = runif(min = -9, max = -6, n = 300),
                      lat = runif(min = 51, max = 55, n = 300), 
                      covar1 = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 300), 
                      covar2 = c(randomStrings(n=300, len=3, unique = F, 
                                               upperalpha = T, loweralpha = F, 
                                               digits = F)))

trk <- test_df %>% 
  nest(data = -id) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ {
    make_track(
      .x, lon, lat, 
      all_cols = TRUE,
      crs = 4326, 
      check_duplicates = FALSE, 
      verbose = TRUE)}))
```

And apply whichever function needed on each element of the list-column.

```
trk1 <- trk %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ mutate(.x, sl = step_lengths(.x)))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = data)
```

Unfortunately, `trk1` loses the `track_xy` classes. I file an issue for this.

Answer (score 0):

`unnest_legacy()` worked pretty good for me:

```
    trk <- mov %>% amt::make_track(.x = X, .y = Y, .t = datetime , crs = 32721, all_cols = TRUE)

    trk_nest <- trk %>% 
      amt::nest(data = -c('Individuo', 'ano')) %>% 
      mutate( 
        sl = amt::map(data, ~ step_lengths(.)),
        ta = amt::map(data, ~ direction_rel(.)) 
      )

    trk_nest %>% unnest_legacy()
```